# Access method for distribution-sampled random numbers generation in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, random, probability-distribution

I am interested in knowing which method Numpy uses in `numpy.random` to generate random numbers distributed as beta, lognormal, Weibull distributions, among others. [In the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html) they often discuss the shape of the distribution, but how can I access to the method? For example, in `numpy.random.chisquare()` [the method is expained](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.chisquare.html#numpy.random.Generator.chisquare), but not in others.

Comment: I don't think that the numpy docs at your link details how it is generated. It tells how to construct it mathematically.

Comment: To learn the exact algorithms used by `numpy.random`, see NumPy's source code: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/main/numpy/random/src/distributions

Answer (score 0):

Pseudorandom numbers start their life as uniformly distributed integers over the whole number representation space and then transformed into the desired shapes and ranges using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling. While the descriptions [usually](https://www.av8n.com/physics/arbitrary-probability.htm) suppose a uniform distribution of real numbers on [0,1], it is straightforward to imagine the transformation of getting the uniform distribution on [0,1] from one on the range [0,2^{64}]. In [numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1995e2cdfd17ec75e37cc6e69a42ce9000aac966/numpy/random/tests/test_direct.py#L83-L100), it is done like this:

```py
def uniform_from_uint64(x):
    return (x >> np.uint64(11)) * (1.0 / 9007199254740992.0)


def uniform_from_uint32(x):
    out = np.empty(len(x) // 2)
    for i in range(0, len(x), 2):
        a = x[i] >> 5
        b = x[i + 1] >> 6
        out[i // 2] = (a * 67108864.0 + b) / 9007199254740992.0
    return out
```

Things get non-trivial in higher dimensions ([as early as in 2D](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/uniform-to-normal-distribution#box-muller-transform)), especially when it comes to efficiency.